# Armature not working correctly

Tags: modeling

Hi how can I make this bone for each finger  move just that finger?

[image]
[image]
I used the old parenting method.

Comment: Can someone help me please

Comment: You need an Armature modifier on the mesh and you need to weight paint, try searching the web for a tutorial that fits your learning style. There are many out there :)

Comment: For starters, try [**this tutorial**](http://www.blendernation.com/2013/11/13/intro-to-weight-painting-in-blender-3d/) I can't preview it to see if it is what you want exactly (out of town), but it should help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your mesh appears to have backwards "normals". Flip the normals, then try the parenting method again with automatic weights. It should work!